# Error: req.flash() requires sessions

Tags: node.js, flash, express

I'm new to node and I'm pretty sure I've set up the middle ware and express to use flash messaging however I still get the error:

`Error: req.flash() requires sessions`

**Setup**

```
//express.js
     var flash = require('connect-flash')

     module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {
         app.use(flash());
     };

//route js
     exports.loginGet = function (req, res) {
       res.render('users/login', {
         title: 'Login',
         message: req.flash('error') //error in question
       });
     };
```

What else can I do to make sure I have everything set up correctly and get it working?

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#express-3x. You need to use session middleware, thus the error message `req.flash() requires sessions`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [readme](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/blob/master/README.md) (emphasis mine):

> Flash messages are stored in the session. **First, setup sessions as usual by enabling cookieParser and session middleware.** Then, use flash middleware provided by connect-flash.

Using `express-sessions` with express 4, `cookieParser` is no longer required.

```
var session = require('express-session');

//...


app.use(session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, 
                  secret: 'woot',
                  resave: false, 
                  saveUninitialized: false}));
```

Comment: isn't using express.XXX from express v2 and 3? I thought they removed this features from express and made them single middleware?

Comment: My bad - you are correct. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was that Redis was not listening. I found that out by enabling the `logErrors` property:

```js
new RedisStore({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '6379',
  logErrors: true,
});
```

Which resulted in messages like these:

```
Warning: connect-redis reported a client error: Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check mongodb connections. there may be an mongo error like "mongoError: Topology was destroyed".
To fix this issue, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed)

Comment: This helped me fix the same error message caused by a misconfigured (wrong host name)  using connect-redis session

Answer (score 2):

i was having these issues and I solve them by respecting the cascading

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//SESSION FLASH
app.use(flash());
```