# Reconnection to the failed mongo server

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm connecting to the mongo with reconnect options on the startup and using created db over the whole app.

```
var options = {
    "server": {
      "auto_reconnect": true,
      "poolSize": 10,
      "socketOptions": {
        "keepAlive": 1
       }
    },
    "db": {
      "numberOfRetries": 60,
      "retryMiliSeconds": 5000
    }
  };

MongoClient.connect(dbName, options).then(useDb).catch(errorHandler)
```

When I restart mongo server, driver reconnect successful. If I stop server and start it after a 30 second I get MongoError "topology was destroyed" on every operation. This 30 second seems to me is a default value for numberOfRetries = 5 and my given option doesn't have effect. Am I doing something wrong? How can I manage reconnection for a long time?

Comment: Have you tried the solution from my answer?

Comment: Yes I have tried, without any changes :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33163368/236660), in order to fix this error, you should increase connection timeout in the options:

```js
var options = {
  "server": {
    "auto_reconnect": true,
    "poolSize": 10,
    "socketOptions": {
      "keepAlive": 1,
      "connectTimeoutMS": 30000 // increased connection timeout
     }
  },
  "db": {
    "numberOfRetries": 60,
    "retryMiliSeconds": 5000
  }
};
```