# Node.js MongoDB insert error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, facebook-messenger

```
function uploadVote(voter, vote){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection('testvote', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({"psid": voter}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(!result[0]){
                db.collection("testvote").insert({psid: "a", choice:0}, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    console.log('insertone')
                    sendTextMessage(". ")
                });
            } else if(!result[0].choice){
                db.collection("testvote").update({psid: voter}, {$set: {'choice': vote}}, function(err, res){
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    sendTextMessage(". ")
                })
            } else{
                sendTextMessage(voter, "!");
            }

        });
        db.close(); 
    });
})
}
```

Hi, I'm developing a facebook messenger that let users vote something. In the code above, I see no syntax error at all. But when this function is executed it keeps making a error:

```
/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
2017-05-18T12:09:19.856188+00:00 app[web.1]:     process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
2017-05-18T12:09:19.856188+00:00 app[web.1]:                                   ^
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858765+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ReplSet.insert (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/replset.js:398:18)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858761+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: topology was destroyed
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ReplSet.insert (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1025:47)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at executeCommands (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:455:23)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at OrderedBulkOperation.execute (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:508:10)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858767+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bulkWrite (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:664:8)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Collection.insertMany (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:534:44)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858769+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:121:41
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Collection.insert (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:836:15)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858770+00:00 app[web.1]:     at handleCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
2017-05-18T12:09:19.858771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:860:16
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoError: Topology was destroyed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed)

Comment: I think your `db.close()` call might be run before the callback that gets passed to your `collection.find()` call. This would mean that by the time the subsequent `insert()` or `update()` calls get made, the database connection has been closed

Comment: Thanks for your help! Then how I should I edit my codes?

Comment: just put your db.close() inside your callback

Comment: You need to make sure that `db.close()` only gets called after you are done with it. You could either just put it at the end of each code branch (i.e. after each case of `sendTextMessage()`) or wrap the whole thing in a promise and call resolve in those locations instead. I'll write an answer below.

Comment: Thanks you so much....I will be waiting for your answer. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database calls will be asynchronous meaning that the `db.close()` line will be run before the code inside the callbacks.

You need to make sure that `db.close()` only gets called after you are done with the connection. You could either just put it at the end of each code branch (i.e. after each case of `sendTextMessage()`) or wrap the whole thing in a promise and call resolve in those locations instead.

Here is a version of your code wrapped in a promise. The `resolve()` method is only called when you know there are no more requests to be made. You could also not wrap it in a promise and place a `db.close()` statement in each place that I have put a `resolve()` statement.

```js
function uploadVote(voter, vote){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
      if (err) throw err;

      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          db.collection('testvote', function(err, collection) {
              collection.find({"psid": voter}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                  if(!result[0]){
                      db.collection("testvote").insert({psid: "a", choice:0}, function(err, res) {
                          if (err) throw err;

                          console.log('insertone')
                          sendTextMessage(". ")
                          resolve();
                      });
                  } else if(!result[0].choice){
                      db.collection("testvote").update({psid: voter}, {$set: {'choice': vote}}, function(err, res){
                          if (err) throw err; 
                          sendTextMessage(". ")
                          resolve();
                      })
                  } else{
                      sendTextMessage(voter, "!");
                      resolve();
                  }

              });
          });
      }).then(() => db.close());
  })
}
```

Comment: np. also, I just thought you might want to change the `.then(() => db.close())` to `.finally(() => db.close())` and change the throw statements to `reject(err)`. That should make sure that the connection gets closed even if you error out. `.finally` gets run regardless of whether the promise resolves or rejects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a  `MongoError: topology was destroyed` like that, it means your connection to the MongoDB server has been interrupted.  Make sure you have a good connection and it's running when you run your query.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm using MongoDB Atlas and maybe there is a problem with that. Can I have a advice again after I try once more? I appreciate your help so much by the way.