# best way to connect to mongo cluster using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im trying to connect my node app to mongo cluster, and i have used this method

```
var options = {
 useMongoClient: true,
 autoIndex: false, 
 reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
 reconnectInterval: 500, 
 poolSize: 10, 
 bufferMaxEntries: 0
};

var cluster = "my cluster url XXX";
mongoose.connect(cluster, options);
```

but it throwing this error

> (node:8701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): MongoError: topology was destroyed
>   (node:8701) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that a
>   re not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I know this is not the right way to connect to a cluster.
can anyone please tell me which is the best method and why (with an example)
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoError: Topology was destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+ip+':'+port+'/'+database, function(err) {});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {});
```