# Finding by Id is not working in Nodejs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection('test').find({"title":"I like cake"}/*,{projection:{_id:true}}*/).toArray(function(err, results){
            if(err) throw err;

            id = "5b7fb08f823d6137e08a7d8a";
        });

        db.collection('test').findOne({_id: new ObjectId(id)}, function(err, results){
            if(err) throw err;  
            console.log(results);
        });
```

it' not work. (return null)
following example is work.

```
db.collection('test').find({"title":"I like cake"}/*,{projection:{_id:true}}*/).toArray(function(err, results){
            if(err) throw err;

        });

        db.collection('test').findOne({_id: new ObjectId("5b7fb08f823d6137e08a7d8a")}, function(err, results){
            if(err) throw err;  
            console.log(results);
        });
```

What's the difference?
How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue is that you are setting the `ID` in a callback function which is asynchronous. Thus, when the `findOne` query executes, the `ID` is not yet set.

You might want to move the second query inside the callback function itself:

```
db.collection("test")
  .find({ title: "I like cake" } /*,{projection:{_id:true}}*/)
  .toArray(function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var id = "5b7fb08f823d6137e08a7d8a";

    db.collection("test").findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, function(err,results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(results);
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for answer. when i user this code, occur this error "MongoError: Topology was destroyed"

Comment: That seems more of a connection issue. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed

Comment: thanks! i called close() out of callback

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: @김동환 Hey Thanks for accepting the answer, If you could also upvote, that would help :)

Comment: I wanna do that. but i don't know how can i get reputations, so i'm searching that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 db.collection("test").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   db.collection("test").find({
     _id:new ObjectID('5b7fb08f823d6137e08a7d8a')
     }).toArray(function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
     //db.close();
   });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for answer. when i user this code, occur this error "MongoError: Topology was destroyed"

Comment: i updated the code