# Mocha MongoDB clean collection before each test

Tags: mongodb, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to cleanup 2 collections before each test. I'm using `mocha --watch` to rerun tests while editing the test source files. First run always executes as expected, but consecutive runs gives `Topology was destroyed` error from mongodb(indicated via result of http request).

I am not really sure why `deleteMany` deletes my inserted object in consecutive runs.

```
describe('myCollection1 related tests', () => {
    // myCollection1 documents should refer to a valid myCollection2 document.
    var foo;
    const exampleObject = {name: 'TEST OBJECT', attr1: 'TO'};
    beforeEach(() => {
        return Promise.all([
            mongo.db('mydb').collection('myCollection1').deleteMany({}), // clear collection 1
            mongo.db('mydb').collection('myCollection2').deleteMany({}) // clear collection 2
            .then(() => mongo.db('mydb').collection('myCollection2').insertOne(exampleObject) // and add a sample object
            .then((value) => {
                foo = value.ops[0]; // save this as test specific variable so I can use it in my tests.
                return Promise.resolve();
            })),
        ]);
    });

    it('should create a related object', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/v1/foos/')
            .send({ related: foo._id })
            .then((res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.be.an('object').with.all.keys('status', 'errors', 'data');
                done();
            }).catch((err) => {
                done(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I spotted issue with your promise structure in `beforeEach`. I'm not sure it is intended or not. I'm afraid it is the culprit. I'm fixing that into below:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    return Promise.all([
        mongo.db('mydb').collection('myCollection1').deleteMany({}),
        mongo.db('mydb').collection('myCollection2').deleteMany({})
      ]) // close the promise.all here
      .then(() => collections.engines().insertOne(exampleObject)) // close `then` here
      .then((value) => {
        foo = value.ops[0];
        return Promise.resolve();
      });
  });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it was not the culprit :) My intent was clear the collection2 and add a sample object, in both case it does the same thing(just checked to be sure). But this fix an oversight of having another level of indentation.

Comment: I see. I'm looking for `Topology was destroyed` and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed. Have you checked this out?

Comment: I was trying to use same connection for tests and api itself. Due to nodejs require caching I was getting already closed connection in my express app. Thanks for the link, I assumed it was trying to read a deleted record.