# MongoDB :An error occurred while loading navigation: topology was destroyed

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was working in my express project and suddenly I got Database related error.

When I refreshed my mongoDB database it shows me an error related to DATA Destroyed.I was shocked .But I was having backup of my DB collections so I droped my database and did restore again but then also I got the same error after some . 
   When I tried to hit the API it works and fetch data.But in my mongo compass it shows null .

This happens me a lot in past two days.some times DB shows non of the data but when I tried to hit the API it works and fetch data some times & some times it shows error.

Is there any permanent solution for this?

Versions of packages I'm using :

- mongoose: 5.6.1
- Node : 1.18.10
- Express: 4.16.3

Comment: It mostly has to do with mongoose connections dropping in b/w a process. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30909492/6082280). Might help.