# Topology was Destroyed / Topology was closed - MongoDB(Mongoose) - Discord.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, topology

I keep on trying to implement MongoDB in my code using `Mongoose`, but in most of my commands that I add it in, it returns with either `'Topology was destroyed'` or `'Topology was closed'` and I can't find a way to fix the problem.

I followed along with tutorials on YT from (Worn Off keys) and changed it a bit and it didn't seem to work, and then I copied and pasted his one to see if it works but I get the same error.

Is there something I should check that I might have done wrong like in the schemas or connecting to MongoDB(even though I followed what was said in the videos) please let me know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoError: Topology was destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed)

Comment: Compare your code to official documentation carefully, most likely you got the scopes wrong on various operations.