# How to send message to front-end using Passport.js Strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

newbie with Passport.js here trying to do a simple thing. I just want to send a custom message to my front-end, im using "passport": "^0.4.0", and "express": "^4.17.0", and "passport-local": "^1.0.0", but i cant seem to get it working. I saw something about this being different with express 4, tried to download connect-flash but didnt manage to get it working.

This sends a message with error normally:

```
res.status(401).send({
    message: 'Authentication key expired'
});
```

Now im trying to do this with passport strategy, <strike>but doesnt seem to send anything to the client</strike> but it sends a generic 401 with no custom message:

```
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField: "login", passwordField: "password"}, (login, password, done) => {
      User.findByLogin(login).then(async user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        let subscription = await user.getValidSubscription();
        if (!subscription) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Your subscription has expired.'
          });
        }
        user.dataValues.expiration = subscription.expiration;
        return done(null, user);
      });
    })
  );
```

Again, im aware that this is a problem with flash messages and stuff, but **isnt there an easy way out just to send a custom message?** All i need is that the 'Incorrect username' reaches my front-end.
Ive spent some days into this and still nothing.
Thank you in advance!

Edit1: Made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install flash with `npm install connect-flash`

After that go to your app.js file and write these:

`var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash())`

Inside your passport function 
add this 
passReqToCallback

`{
usernameField : 'login',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true }// allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback`

And then inside your parameters (login, password, done) you can pass the request object like this `(req,login, password, done)`

Finally you can send message like this

`if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
 return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Incorrect username.'));
}`

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help, did what u said and got the error:
        Unhandled rejection Error: req.flash() requires sessions
        at IncomingMessage._flash [as flash] (c:\Users\R2\Documents\Projects\server- 
   eusaudavel\node_modules\connect-flash\lib\flash.js:60:41)
        at User.findByLogin.then (c:\Users\R2\Documents\Projects\server- 
   eusaudavel\routes\passport.js:31:40)
        at tryCatcher (c:\Users\R2\Documents\Projects\server- 
   eusaudavel\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23) ...

Comment: Also, if i try this (from the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563321/error-req-flash-requires-sessions
i get:
NodeError: Invalid status code: 1
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (c:\Users\R2\Documents\Projects\server-eusaudavel\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:200:8)...

Comment: Using 
    return done(null, false, req.flash('Incorrect password.'));
instead of 
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Incorrect username.'));
doesnt give me invalid status code: 1, but it still only gives a generic 401 response